# How do I put my automatic car into neutral while moving in drive?

Tags: engine, car, shifting

I have a friend that is always putting his car in neutral and revving it up and I find that the coolest thing in the world. If someone could tell me how I can put my 2006 Civic in neutral while in motion that would be amazing.

Comment: "I find that the coolest thing in the world"  great question

Comment: I'm now starting to regret I bought a hybrid, because on my car pressing the accelerator does nothing when the gear selector is in neutral.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this while the car's moving. When the car's in neutral, the engine is not attached to the wheels so you have lost one option to control the car.

Comment: Besides the fact that many of us will be looking/hearing you do that and think you are **not** cool (to put it gently), I hope that you are aware that if you cause an accident this will be an aggravating cause against you.

Comment: And I am depressed, becuase I  can't figure out how to rev my Segway :-(

Comment: _"The coolest thing in the world"_? Really? The sea is cool, spaceships are cool, IMAX is cool. This is dangerous. Your "friend" is potentially putting himself, yourself and others at risk of their lives. Just drive properly for goodness's sakes!

Comment: Agree with other commenters but also consider that needlessly revving the engine pollutes the environment with fuel that could be used to transport you somewhere useful; costs you money; wears down the expensive mechanic parts in your engine to no effect other than making you go "COOL!"; and uses up precious fossil fuel resources that **will** run out (unless you believe the Earth is of infinite size).

Answer (score 14):

You can put your car into neutral by moving the gear selector into the position marked "N".

Comment: Should a person who does not know this be in possession  of a driving license?

Comment: @Mawg: Absolutely not. Sadly, many people seem to drive without them.

Comment: @Mawg I've possessed a driving license for nearly 50 years, and never yet driven an automatic. But I don't live in a the USA! In fact in the UK there is a special class of licence for people who passed their driving test in an automatic and therefore can *not* legally drive *manual* transmission vehicles - and similar restrictions apply to visitors with driving licences issued by some other countries.

Comment: I only ever drove automatic when forced to by rental companies in the USA. Otherwise, decdes of manual (stick shift) for me too. And, no, I don't reve at lights, despite having a sporty car

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time (when coming to a stop). Don't hit the shifter button, just gently tap the shifter forwards into "N", same thing to get back into "D".

Revving in neutral is all fun and games, just makes sure the engine goes back down to idling RPMs before getting back into "D". If not, you'll get a big forward lurch, which I don't imagine is too good for the transmission.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your car to "N" just by selecting/changing gear knob/selector to "N".

I drove Grand Cheroke last week and it was awesome experience there I did the same, press the button on gear shaft(selector) and move to 'N'